# Access to a specific attribute from another model

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8yoc.png)

Hi, guys!!
I attached the image with the field I would like to see in the table. However, I was checking my blade template and I could find why I don´t have access to that attribute. I created a specific relation between models, but it seems that is impossible to extract this information from the database.

Here is the model

```
class Booking_Stays_Abroad extends Model
{

     /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'booking__stays__abroads';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
                  'id_stays_abroad',
                  'user_id',
                  'status',
                  'departure_date',
                  'return_date',
                  'number_weeks',
              ];


    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [];

     /**
     * Set and get the departure_date
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */

    public function setDepartureDateAttribute($value):void
    {
        $this->attributes['departure_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function getDepartureDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format(config('app.date_format'));
    }


    /**
     * Set and get the return_date.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */

    public function setReturnDateAttribute($value):void
    {
        $this->attributes['return_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat(config('app.date_format'), $value)->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function getReturnDateAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->format(config('app.date_format'));
    }

    public function stays_abroad()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stays_Abroad::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

The other one

```
class Stays_Abroad extends Model
{

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'stays_abroads';

    /**
    * The database primary key value.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
                  'location',
                  'county',
                  'nation',
                  'country',
                  'school',
                  'accommodation',
                  'landmarks',
                  'price_week'
              ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [];

    /**
     * Set the return_date.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */


    public function booking_stays_abroad()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Booking_Stays_Abroad::class);
    }

}
```

And this is the blade templaate

```html
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('id_stays_abroad') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="id_stays_abroad" class="col-md-2 control-label">Id Stays Abroad</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="id_stays_abroad" name="id_stays_abroad">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('id_stays_abroad', optional($bookingStaysAbroad)->id_stays_abroad ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select id_stays_abroad</option>
         @foreach ($staysAbroads as $key => $staysAbroad)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('id_stays_abroad', optional($bookingStaysAbroad)->id_stays_abroad ?: '') == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $staysAbroad }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select> 

        {!! $errors->first('id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('user_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="user_id" class="col-md-2 control-label">User</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id">
             <option value="" style="display: none;" {{ old('user_id', optional($bookingStaysAbroad)->user_id ?: '') == '' ? 'selected' : '' }} disabled selected>Select user</option>
         @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('user_id', optional($bookingStaysAbroad)->user_id) == $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $user }}
       </option>
   @endforeach
        </select>

        {!! $errors->first('user_id', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('departure_date') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="departure_date" class="col-md-2 control-label">Departure Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control datepicker" name="departure_date" type="text" id="departure_date" value="{{ old('departure_date', optional($staysAbroad)->departure_date) }}" placeholder="Enter departure date here...">
        {!! $errors->first('departure_date', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('return_date') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="return_date" class="col-md-2 control-label">Return Date</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control datepicker" name="return_date" type="text" id="return_date" value="{{ old('return_date', optional($staysAbroad)->return_date) }}" placeholder="Enter return date here...">
        {!! $errors->first('return_date', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('price_week') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="number_weeks" class="col-md-2 control-label">Number of Weeks</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="number_weeks" type="number" id="number_weeks" value="{{ old('price_week', optional($staysAbroad)->price_week) }}" minlength="1" placeholder="Enter price week here...">
        {!! $errors->first('price_week', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

To be brief, I want to extract the **location** attribute that belong to Stays_Abroad model and shown into the index.blade.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your model Booking_Stays_Abroad has foreign key as 'id_stays_abroad'. When you create a relation in Stays_Abroad model like this return $this->hasMany(Booking_Stays_Abroad::class), it expects the foreign key in the Bookin__Stays__Abroad to be like 'stays_abroad_id'. So, either correct the foreign key in the other table or explicitely mention the foreign key like

```
public function booking_stays_abroad()
{
    return $this>hasMany(Booking_Stays_Abroad::class, 'id_stays_abroad', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem remains. No changes et all. I forgot to comment that I added a migration with the foreign keys for booking_stays_abroad